# How to add a number of row from df that meets the criteria in the for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R. I want to know which row from the `seq` meets the criteria (is >= 10).

```
    df1 <- data.frame(value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), 
                          aa = c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','Y'))
        
    seq <- data.frame(aa = c("ABC","BCD","CDE","DEF","EFG"))
          
          counter = 0;
          y  <- NULL;
          for (i in seq$aa) {
          df_splited<- strsplit(i, "") #split aa
          df_new <- do.call(cbind, df_splited) 
          df_2 <- as.data.frame(df_new) 
          counter = counter + 1
          new_df <- df_2 %>% #match two dfs
           pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = 'aa') %>%
           left_join(df1, by = 'aa')
           new_df$value <- sum(new_df) #summarise value
          res <- new_df  %>% filter(value >= 10) #if value >= 10 print it out
          
          y <- rbind(y, res)
          print(y)
        }
```

Expected outcome for res:

```
value   row_n  
12        3
15        4
18        5
```

I don't know how to add row_n to the outcome to the for loop.

Let's take the first example ("ABC"):

```
from df1 we know that: A = 1 ; B = 2 ; C = 3 
the sum of ABC = 6
```

since sum for ABC is not equal or greater than 10 it will be ignored for the final output.

For "EFG" the sum is 18 so it will be included in the final output.
Then I would like to know that EFG was the one that met the criteria so ideally the output would be a row from the `seq` that met criteria.

Comment: Can you please explain in a it more detail what exactly you want to achieve based on our input data? E.g. what should be >= 10? BTW your code already fails in the first row of the loop.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know - if you assign each letter in seq a number of the alphabet, which combination in seq would have a sum >=10?

Comment: just updated the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the values of the strings in `seq` like this:

```r
seq$val <- sapply(strsplit(seq$aa, ""), function(x) sum(df1$value[match(x, df1$aa)]))
```

So that `seq` becomes:

```r
seq
#>    aa val
#> 1 ABC   6
#> 2 BCD   9
#> 3 CDE  12
#> 4 DEF  15
#> 5 EFG  18
```

And you can do

```
 seq[seq$val > 10,]
#>    aa val
#> 3 CDE  12
#> 4 DEF  15
#> 5 EFG  18
```

Answer (score 1):

a (bit more verbose) tidyverse approach (assuming you only want to calcualte the sum for a three-letter combination):

```
seq %>%
  mutate(split = str_split(aa, "")) %>%
  unnest_wider(split, names_repair = ~c("aa", paste0("letter_", 1:3))) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("letter_"), match, df1$aa),
         letter_sum = apply(across(starts_with("letter_")), 1, sum))
```

also gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  aa    letter_1 letter_2 letter_3 letter_sum
  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int>      <int>
1 ABC          1        2        3          6
2 BCD          2        3        4          9
3 CDE          3        4        5         12
4 DEF          4        5        6         15
5 EFG          5        6        7         18
```